# How can I add JFace source in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jface

According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace  I should find JFace source in `plugins\org.eclipse.rpc.source_<version>`.

> 21. Now press the `Extension...` button. This will open the Variable Extension Selection dialog. Again, expand the plugins directory. Find the directory called `org.eclipse.rcp.source_<version infomation>`. Note that this is a directory, not a JAR file.
> 22. Expand this directory, expand the `src` subdirectory, scroll down to the directory called `org.eclipse.jface_<version information>`. Expand this, and select the file called `src.zip`.

After installing `Eclipse platform SDK` I got this directory (in `features\org.eclipse.rcp.source_4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h` instead of `plugins`) but  I can only find the `META-INF` folder but no `src` folder, neither can I find the `src.zip`

How can I add JFace source to a jar in Eclipse? What Eclipse 4.2 package contains it?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the SWT repository [hosted at this URL](http://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/), which contains e.g. jface 3.8.0 and swt 4.4 (both including sources)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching src folders and src.zip files in these folders 
look for "org.eclipse...source...jar" files in the plugin folder.

For example org.eclipse.jface.source_3.13.2.v20171022-1656.jar

It works at least for my Eclipse Oxigen. 
If you have not such files install "Eclipse SDK" plugin and try again